# PHP url redirect on PORT access

Tags: php, redirect, port

Its been full day googling my requirement but had no luck!

I want to make an "Admin Panel" for a website but dont want anyone to guess and hit admin area.
Like: "http://www.mysite.com/admin" OR "http://admin.mysite.com/".

I want admin login to be displayed on accessing a port
Like: "http://www.mysite.com:3535/" and this URL redirect to my admin area.

Should i look into .htaccess or PHP can do this alone?

Comment: Security through obscurity is not a very good solution. A simple mmap on the server and they will find out that port 3535 is hosting a webserver.

Comment: why do you care if someone guesses the log in url?

Comment: Neither '.htaccess' nor PHP will help you. You have to tell Apache to listen specified port and, probably, create a virtual host for it. Read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html Only after that you will be able to forward requests somewhere else.

Comment: Actually my client reffered me to "www.mysite.com:2083" which redirects to the hosting account of the site. He wanted me to do the same for the admin panel :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a webserver listening on that port you can't do that. You could run 2 webservers on one machine, one listening on port 80 (the default http port) and another running on port 3535 which simply redirects to another location but that <strike>sounds</strike> *is* silly.

There are better ways to securing your application from intrusion than just hiding your login page, google for it.

Comment: Actually my client reffered me to "www.mysite.com:2083" which redirects to the hosting account of the site. He wanted me to do the same for the admin panel :(

Comment: Are you sure it redirects or is it actually hosted on that port? If so you should just be running your webserver on the specified port, nothing to do with redirects.